# Is it possible to run an EXE within a browser?

Tags: windows, browser

Is it possible to run an EXE within a browser?  I do not mean launch from browser only (which i know can be done using IE), but I wish to run the EXE from within the browser so it appears to the user as a web based application.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you intend to avoid the security nightmare of running dangerous programs from the browser?

Comment: No, this is not possible for innumerable reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. there are alot of issues which that concept regarding UI, Security etc..
the closest i've come to see is using [Google Native Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client) which uses a *sandbox* to run native code.

Comment: Thanks Orentet, can't really use Google Native Client as my app is done in Delphi, so will have to redevelop, and if that's the case, I might as well redo as webapp.  :)